# fullCalendar business hours only activatedfor current week

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am using jquery FullCalendar.

I have set business hours and default view AgendaWeek.

The issue I have is that if I go back one week, the entire calendar is greyed out.
Only the current week which is the one I land on by default is not greyed out between business hours.

How can I have business hours repeat for all weeks ?

THanks a lot  !

My setup:

```
    $calendar.fullCalendar({
        lang: '{{ app.request.locale }}',
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
        businessHours:
        {
            start: '08:00',
            end: '18:00',
            dow: [1,2,3,4,5,6] // Monday is not a working day
        },
        timeFormat: 'H(:mm)',
        editable: true,
        allDayDefault: false,
        timezone: 'Europe/Berlin',
        firstDay: 1,
        droppable: true
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem is solved in the latest version of fullCalendar.

Comment: I should and I will ;)